# SDL2 Handling non character key presses as the same natural delay rate as SDL_TextInputEvent

Tags: c, input, sdl, d, sdl-2

In SDL2 there is an event SDL_TextInputEvent which captures input from the keyboard at the natural rate the OS is configured to be.
When I poll events, it's something like this:

```
SDL_Event event;
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    switch (event.type) {
    case SDL_TEXTINPUT:
        Input_Listener.last_key = event.text.text;
        break;
    default: 
        break;
    }
}
```

The `event.text.text` is a `char[32]` which contains the character in UTF-8 which the user inputs in the program. This is great as the delay is fine, so if you hold down the `a` key it wont insert loads of `a` characters as fast as possible.

However, this event doesn't seem to capture non-character input like pressing the enter key or the arrow keys. I can, however, capture them like so:

```
ubyte* states = SDL_GetKeyboardState(null);
if (states[SDL_SCANCODE_BACKSPACE]) {
    ... do stuff here 
}
```

However this does *not* have the OS delay, and will fire as quickly as possible. My program is a text editor, but it's programmed as if it was a game. So there is a game loop, update/rendering methods, etc. Meaning that the check for input is done constantly every frame.

What can I do to get the non-character input at the same delay rate as the OS is configured? Is there some function I'm missing, or some way I can simulate this?

Comment: Text input is for, well, text input (language-aware, etc.). You probably want to use `SDL_KEYDOWN/SDL_KEYUP` events instead of both text input and `GetKeyboardState`.

Comment: You should always use text for text input only and not for keyboard states at all. This is common practice in most libraries similar to SDL such as sfml.

Comment: I managed to solve my issue by using TextInputEvent for text input, and the KeyDown/Up Events for the key pressed stuff.

Comment: PS. you can write an answer to your own question, and accept it. That is allowed, and if written well we (the community) will probably reward it with few upvotes.